# Adding multiple columns in between columns in a data frame using a For Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, match

**outputdata (df)**

```
Store.No  Task 
    1      70
    2      50
    3      20
```

I am trying to add 53 columns after the 'Task' column by using its position not the name. Then I want want columns names to begin from 1 and end on the number 53 with 0 in the rows. The rows in this example go to row number 3 but it could vary so would it be possible to use nrow function to specify the number of rows rather than hard coding

**outputdata- Desired Outcome**

```
    Store.No  Task  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 ...53
       1      70    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       2      50    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       3      20    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

**Code used**

```
x <- 1
y <- 0

for (i in 1:53){

 outputdata <- add_column(outputdata, x = 0, .after = Fo+y)
 y <- y + 1
 x <- x + 1

}
```

The error i'm getting is the columns are being called x,x.1,x.2,x.3,x.4...x.53. Rather than 1,2,3,4...53...not too sure why this could be

I am still quite new to R so there is a far more efficient way of doing this then please let me know

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to loop to do this:

```
as.data.frame(cbind(df, matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = 53)))

 Store.No Task Third Fourth 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
1        1   70     4      7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2        2   50     5      8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3        3   20     6      9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

1. `matrix` will create a matrix with 53 columns and 3 rows filled with `0`
2. `cbind` will add this matrix to the end of your data
3. `as.data.frame` will convert it to a dataframe

**Update**

To insert these zero columns positionally you can subset your `df` into two parts: `df[, 1:2]` are the first and second columns, while `df[,3:ncol(df)]` are the third to end of your dataframe.

```
as.data.frame(cbind(df[,1:2], matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = 53), df[,3:ncol(df)))

Store.No Task 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
1        1   70 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2        2   50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3        3   20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 Third Fourth
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     4      7
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     5      8
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     6      9
```

**add_column**

Alternatively you can use the `add_column` function from the `tibble` package as you were in your post using the `.after` argument to insert after the second column:

```
library(tibble)

tibble::add_column(df, as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = 53)), .after = 2)
```

Note: this function will fix the column names to add a "V" before any column name that starts with a number. So `1` will become `V1`.

---

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Store.No = 1:3,
                 Task = c(70, 50, 20),
                 Third = 4:6,
                 Fourth = 7:9)
```

Comment: How would this work with more than 3 rows? the row number can change each time...usually starting from 1400 rows

Comment: Change `nrow = 1400`

Comment: couldn't there be a way to use the nrow function rather than specifying the amount of rows?

Comment: Most likely, but information about how/when the number of rows changes is not provided in your post. You could make it more generic by specifying `nrow = nrow(df)`.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the original post

Comment: No problem, I actually misread your comment about using the function. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I probably would need to ask another question or would it be okay to update this one? Because I also wanted to know what would happen if in the df the 'Task' column wasn't the last column - which is what i was inferring to when by i mentioned I need by column position (so I can reference after the 2nd position then put the 53 number columns after it). I think your code above will just concatenate on the end of the df...is this the case?

Comment: Yes, it will always add these columns to the end of the dataframe. So if you had a third column, then these 53 would be added after that third column.

Comment: Is there a way to do it based on the position of a column...so I can say something like after column[2] then add 53 columns

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer with how to do this.